# Make pip stop if any kind of error happened

Tags: pip

I'm creating an installation in which all pip packages have to work.
But when I'm installing packages from requirements.txt, even if some packages failed, it will still continue installation as usual.
Is there any way to stop the entire installation and throw an error?

Thanks!